# Remove special character \r carriage return from column headers

Tags: python, pandas

How do we remove special characters in the header of a csv file?

`Col1\r -> Column name`

In `Col1\r` we would basically see it as `Col1`, which is actually not visible when opened in Excel.

I have moved the data to a dataframe `df`.

```
# Remove special characters from column headers  
dfcolumns = df.columns
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\r', '')
```

More information [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where are you taking the column name from. If it's a json you need to open it with the propper encoding. If you have this string handled by another varaiable in plain text, you need to manipulate it and clean the bad values. with

```
string_variable.replace('\r', '')
```